# find average velocity

Tags: calculus

displacement function : $f(t)=pt^2+qt$

with $p=0.40m/s^2$ and $q=-1.2m/s$

find the average velocity between t=0 and t=1

I derived the displacement function to velocity function, $f'(t)=2pt+q$

when I substitude $f'(1)=2(0.40m/s^2)(1)-1.2m/s=\frac {0.8m-1.2ms}{s^2}$

the SI unit doesn't seem correct here, or any step gone wrong during calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't input $1$, that represents time! It is actually $1 s$ (1 second); if you do that, you'll end up with $m/s$ which is correct since it's a velocity.

Do you know how to find the average velocity? (you need to integrate $f'(t)$ between $0$ and $1$ :-) )